# Appium-chromedriver custom profile

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, appium

Is there a way to use the custom profile on android with appium and chromedriver?
I am trying to define the ChromeOptions as follows `chromeOptions = {'args': ['user-data-dir=/data/user/0/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/']}`
After I launch chrome with the use of chromedriver and check the `chrome://version` I see profile path as `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default` and there is no user signed in to chrome.

This is the log for appium starting

```
[debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "alwaysMatch": {
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "platformName": "Android",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "browserName": "Chrome",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:platformVersion": "11",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:deviceName": "992AY188TB",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:chromedriverExecutable": "/Users/chromedriver",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:showChromedriverLog": "true",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:newCommandTimeout": "3000",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:noReset": "true",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:fullReset": "false",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:chromeOptions": {
[debug] [BaseDriver]       "args": [
[debug] [BaseDriver]         "user-data-dir=/data/user/0/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/"
[debug] [BaseDriver]       ]
[debug] [BaseDriver]     }
[debug] [BaseDriver]   },
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "firstMatch": [
[debug] [BaseDriver]     {}
[debug] [BaseDriver]   ]
[debug] [BaseDriver] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add chrome options via [Appium capabilities](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/), use `chromeOptions`.

Keep in mind, not all the options are accepted on Android, you can find supported in code [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/capabilities.cc#544)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I have appium:chromeOptions in use. I made an edit in the Question to make that more clear. Am I using it wrong ? I was checking the usage from [here]https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities .